# Can I see always time in console?

Tags: scripting, date

I would like to set the Linux console such that it shows the current time always in console's upper right corner. Is that possible to do? Or is it wise to do if one can never be sure if the cursor is updating time or reading input? I know the command watch but as I tried, it cleared the whole screen instead just showing the time.

Comment: Even if it is possible I don't think it is wise, this is more the sort of thing for a GUI. You can always just type `date` at the prompt, or look at your watch ;-)

Comment: Why do you wanna do that ?

Comment: You can do this in the statusline of GNU `screen`

Comment: why waste valuable vertical screen space in your terminal when most window managers and desktop environments have panels or similar and clock apps for those panels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can setup a `screen` or `tmux` hardline.

Example using [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/): http://blog.boreas.ro/2008/03/gnu-screen-for-win.html

Example using [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/):

[image: tmux]

`tmux` and `screen` are awesome - you should learn how to use them.